# I am using Yiistrap. I want to modify content of model

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions, yii-components

I am using Yiistrap. I want to modify content of model. I want to add some label, text box, drop-down (2 or more fields). I have given the code below & mentioned the region which I want to modify.

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbModal', array(
'id' => 'myModal',
'header' => 'Modal Heading',

'content' => '<p>I Wnat to Modify this region</p>', /* Here I don't want only plain text i.e. <p> tag. I want to Add label as well as textbox, dropdown. please help me */

'footer' => implode(' ', array(
    TbHtml::button('Save Changes', array(
        'data-dismiss' => 'modal',
        'color' => TbHtml::BUTTON_COLOR_PRIMARY)
    ),
    TbHtml::button('Close', array('data-dismiss' => 'modal')),
 )), )); ?>

<?php echo TbHtml::button('Click me to open modal', array(
'style' => TbHtml::BUTTON_COLOR_PRIMARY,
'size' => TbHtml::BUTTON_SIZE_LARGE,
'data-toggle' => 'modal',
'data-target' => '#myModal', )); ?>
```